# javascript variable in closure not showing value assigned when initialized by $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

In my app, I have the following closure. It contains a `var`, which is initialized in `$(document).ready`:

```
var myClosure = (function() {
  var thing;

  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      thing = new ClassDefinedInSomeOtherFile();
    }
  )

  return {
    thing: thing
  };
})();
```

As the page loads (I debug in chrome), a breakpoint placed in `$(document).ready()` is reached and I can see `thing` get assigned to an object of *ClassDefinedInSomeOtherFile.*

However, elements attempting to subsequently access `myClosure.thing` encounter errors stating that `myClosure.thing` is undefined (as do calls from the console to `myClosure.thing`). If `thing` was exposed by the `return` block in `myClosure`, why does it not reflect the new value assigned to it, when `$(document).ready()` ran?

Thanks!

Comment: `$(document).ready()` runs asynchronously. The variable isn't assigned yet when you execute the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

you are using [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) so gets executed immediately and return `{ thing: undefined}`, after that when `.ready` event triggers, it runs and change `thing`, but that wont change the returned object, so you would get `myClosure.thing` is `undefined`

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var myClosure = (function() {
  var thing;
  thing = new ClassDefinedInSomeOtherFile();
  return {
    thing: thing
  };
 })()
});
```